# Why an error appears when using the namespace as reference to another in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I want to connect the OdeToFood.Data code with the namespace called OdeToFood.Core that shown in another folder in solution explore

[image]

...but actually it gives me an error that visual studio can accept the OdeToFood.Core as reference

Comment: attempt a build and carefully read the build output. there can be different reasons. examples: difference in bitness, difference in .NET framework version. Sometimes, hovering with the mouse pointer over the offending namespace part (squiggly line) may reveal more information in a tooltip.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/troubleshooting-broken-references?view=vs-2019

Comment: Did you add a reference to OdeToFood.Core on OdeToFood.Data? Right click on OdeToFood.Data -> Add -> Reference -> Select OdeToFood.Core

Answer (score 1):

First of all your project names have nothing to do with the namespaces you use.
If you want your Namespace to be called OdeToFood.Core, then you have to do this:

```
namespace OdeToFood.Core
{

}
```

Further more, if you want your different projects to access each other - you need to reference them.

Click on References -> Add reference -> Other Projects, and pick your project.

Next you need to import the namespace in your project, which is supposed to access that assembly, on top of your file, as you did in your screen:

```
using OdeToFood.Core;
```

Done

Comment: how to get a reference for the startup.cs file in the visual studio2019 because also I want to have a reference for the startup.cs from OdeToFodd.Data file.

Comment: You can't reference files - only namespaces.
If you want to import things in that file - wrap them into the namespace you want to import them with and reference the project where you do.